# set default preferences to the printer through the code

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, printing

Q:

Is there any way to set default setting to the printer through the code , so that i can imagine union and one layout for all users.
this is a web application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes <s>we</s> you can !

Set default styles:

```
<style media = "print">
  @import url("css.css");
</style>
```

And preferences to the printer:

[CSS How-to: Optimize Pages for Printing Using CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html)